# Ruby class with static method calling a private method?

Tags: ruby, static, encapsulation

I have a class with a number of static methods.  Each one has to call a common method, but I'm trying not to expose this latter method.  Making it private would only allow access from an own instance of the class?  Protected does not seem like it would solve the problem here either.

How do I hide do_calc from being called externally in a static context?  (Leaving it available to be called from the first two static methods.)

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    do_calc()
  end
  def self.baz
    do_calc()
  end
  def self.do_calc
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does `self.bar` call a method with parentheses and `self.baz` not?

Comment: I think [`private_class_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method) would fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

First off, `static` is not really part of the *Ruby jargon*.

Let's take a simple example:

```
class Bar
  def self.foo
  end
end
```

It defines the method `foo` on an explicit object, `self`, which in that scope returns the containing class `Bar`.
Yes, it can be defined a *class method*, but *static* does not really make sense in Ruby.

Then `private` would not work, because defining a method on an explicit object (e.g. `def self.foo`) bypasses the access qualifiers and makes the method public.

What you can do, is to use the `class << self` syntax to *open the metaclass* of the containing class, and define the methods there as instance methods:

```
class Foo
  class << self

    def bar
      do_calc
    end

    def baz
      do_calc
    end

    private

    def do_calc
      puts "calculating..."
    end
  end
end
```

This will give you what you need:

```
Foo.bar
calculating...

Foo.baz
calculating...

Foo.do_calc
NoMethodError: private method `do_calc' called for Foo:Class
```

Comment: And the word *lingo* is not part of everybody's vocabulary either ;)

Answer (score 19):

You can define a private class method with [`private_class_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method) like this:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    do_calc
  end

  def self.baz
    do_calc
  end

  def self.do_calc
    #...
  end
  private_class_method :do_calc
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Or as of Ruby 2.1:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    do_calc
  end

  private_class_method def self.do_calc
    #...
  end
end
```