# How come methods under 'private' and 'protected' can always be called in models (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I tested, that they, in fact, don't work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.call_protected_method
    protected_method
  end

  def self.call_private_method
    private_method
  end

  protected

  def self.protected_method
    puts "protected_method"
  end

  private

  def self.private_method
    puts "private_method"
  end

end
```

What i mean, by they don't work, is You can call all methods in this example. It doesn't matter if they are under private and/or protected.

```
# in rails console:
User.call_protected_method # => protected_method
User.protected_method      # => protected_method
User.call_private_method   # => private_method
User.private_method        # => private_method
```

Why is that? Whats the reason for ignoring 'private' and 'protected'?

UPDATE: my question isn't how to do this. My question is why doesn't this approach work in rails models!?

Comment: What did you expect to happen, what happened instead?

Comment: What i mean, by they don't work, is You can call all methods in this example. It doesn't matter if they are under private and/or protected. 

Why is that? Whats the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define a private class method, and that would not work with that syntax. You want [private_class_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method)

Have a look at these answers, too: [Ruby class with static method calling a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737435/ruby-class-with-static-method-calling-a-private-method)

Comment: my question isn't how to do this. My question is why doesn't this approach work in rails models!?

Comment: Rails has nothing to do with it, it's a ruby language feature. This article might explain the reasons why this behaviour exists: http://jakeyesbeck.com/2016/01/24/ruby-private-class-methods/